# Database Model: How to model the roles an employee can act

Tags: database, relationship, data-modeling

I am struggling with this concept in my work DB pet project that handles crews. Each crew member can act in roles (Maintenance Supervisor, Mechanics, Lead Mechanics, Electricians, Automation Leader, etc.). Because crew follows a hierarchy I am interested in build a model where I can save what roles a person can act, for instance: Lead Mechanic can cover absence of a Mechanic, Automation Leader can cover Automation Techs and so on. Each installation has its own training matrix, so it also impact the roles and employees.

One cannot assume Maintenance Supervisor can cover Mechanic position because this person acting as maintenance supervisor came from Automation area and may not act with other disciplines (Electrical, Mechanical, Electronics).

A practical example: Joe is a Mechanic and work in installation A, his main role is a Maintenance Supervisor, because he is a mechanic he can act as Lead Mechanic or Mechanic, but cannot act as any other role in his department, despite being the supervisor of other disciplines. Also because each installation has its own training and competence matrix, Joe is eligible to work in installations A and B but in C.

I have several cases similar to this in various areas, so I realized I have to save these roles a person can act based on their skills. This info is important because when I have to find a cover for a specific role I can check personnel with the same role or supervisors that can fill in as a worst case scenario.

Can someone help me with this conundrum?

[image]

Comment: What is the conundrum you need help with?  From your explanation you seem to have solved the problem - people have skills, roles require skills, roles can only be filled by people with the required skills ... 3 entities and a handful of relationships.  What's the problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Skills are not being tracked, Installations, Employees and Roles are the only entities I have. 

Expanding a little further on the explanation: Joe is a Mechanic and work in installation A, his main role is a Maintenance Supervisor, because he is a mechanic he can act as Lead Mechanic or Mechanic, but cannot act as any other role in his department, despite being the supervisor of other disciplines. Also because each installation has its own training and competence matrix, Joe is eligible to work in installations A and B but in C. 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: *Skills are not being tracked* well, there's your mistake.  Your question makes clear that a match between a Person and a Role is, at least in part, dependent on the Person having the Skills required by the Role.  Your comment has introduced a fourth entity, Installation, so you'll have to model those too.

Comment: OK, let me think on this angle you offered and maybe I will get to a viable solution. Thanks.

Comment: High Performance Mark, I had to put the image on the post.

Comment: I think it's rather odd that Roles attend Traninings.  Otherwise your modelling seems to be going in the right direction.  Have fun.

Comment: Indeed, our business dictates that the Role need to comply with training matrix of the installation, many trainings from the various matrices will overlap. It also means that one employee needs to comply to the installation matrix through the Role he is acting.

Comment: But my business rule is basically this: 

1. An Employee needs a Diploma to be hired and act in a Role
2. Every Installation has its own Training Matrix
3. A Role needs to attend to Training Matrix of the assigned Installation.
4. An employee can act on different Roles only if he has Diploma and attended the trainings necessary based on the installation´s matrix.

Comment: Practical example: John Rambo has been hired as Maintenance Supervisor, he has a Mechanical diploma. this means he can act as Lead Mechanic and Mechanic if necessary. John is assigned to work in Installation B and take all trainings necessary to be compliant. One day, Installation C Mechanic, Sheldon Cooper, calls in sick and John Rambo is the only option we have, but we need to run a gap analysis on his trainings matrix to make sure he has all trainings mandatory and see which ones he will have to take to be sent there.

Comment: The gap analysis detects a 1h course on stainless steel bolts is missing but he can take it online to close it. Then we can enroll him on this training before sending Maintenance Supervisor John Rambo  to installation C to work as a Mechanic and cover Mechanic Sheldon Cooper in Installation C.

Does that make sense to the ER Diagram I came up with?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As a complement, the certificate issued after a course is finished belong to the Employee, so he can fulfill requirements to act in a Role. It means that the relationship between Employee/Certificate and there is another relationship between Role/Employee and another one Installation/Role.